# how to clone a token from the Platform account to a Connect account. when using stripe prebuilt checkout page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I am working on stripe payments, where i require having a shared customer across different connected accounts, that are connected with the platform

I am using "Express Accounts" in stripe connect for connecting the connected accounts, that are linked with the platform account.

On the frontend (client-side) (Angular), using the ["Stripe Prebuilt checkout page"](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder), for accepting payment and I am verifying the payment in webhooks(checkout.session.completed) at backend using Django Rest Framework.

I am using Destination Charges, for handling the payments and separate charges and transfers. (That i am able to achieve using stripe prebuilt checkout page by specifying payment_intent_data.application_fee_amount and payment_intent_data.transfer_data.destination)

Now I have a requirement where I need to have shared customers and share customers across the connected accounts,

i need to create token on connected account level and represent the customer there, a way to link the platform-level customer with the connected account without having to create it again.

I tried to follow this article [Clone customers across accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-saved-payment-methods) but I have not had any luck, unfortunately.

> With Connect, you can accomplish this by following three steps:
>
> 1. Storing customers, with a payment method, on the platform account
> 2. Making tokens to clone the payment method when it’s time to charge
>    the customer on behalf of a connected account
> 3. Creating charges using the new tokens

1. How can i clone a token from the Platform account to a Connect
   account, at what step should i do in stripe prebuilt checkout page ?
2. When should i do it, at the time when i create stripe.checkout.session or in the webhook under this event checkout.session.completed?
3. When i created customer on platofrm, it asks for a source,

> customer = stripe.Customer.create(email='paying.user@example.com',
> source='tok_mastercard', )

what will be the source in my case ? where willi get the source in stripe prebuilt checkout page ?
, i tried to check the logs and events for all 5 webhooks that take place but i am unable to find the source id anywhere in this 5 events:

- charge.succeeded
- payment_method.attached
- customer.created
- payment_intent.succeeded
- checkout.session.completed

and how i will get it ? as i am using checkout api and not the charges api, right ?
I always get this error when i follow that article:

```
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_43rToPlxJsvD: The customer must have an active payment source attached.
```

I can also attach any code for your review and show you what I have tried by now.

Please let me know in the comments if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

> i need to create token on connected account level and represent the
> customer there, a way to link the platform-level customer with the
> connected account without having to create it again.

You can't do this, directly. The connected account has no visibility of the platform customers. You could create a customer on the connected account and use `metadata` to label it with your platform customer, though. eg, set `metadata.platform_cust_id=cus_123`

> How can i clone a token from the Platform account to a Connect
> account, at what step should i do in stripe prebuilt checkout page ?

You'd follow the guide you linked, generally, but you can't do this with Stripe Checkout. Checkout always collects a new Payment Method, so the idea of cloning from the platform is moot.

> what will be the source in my case ? where willi get the source in
> stripe prebuilt checkout page ? , i tried to check the logs and events
> for all 5 webhooks that take place but i am unable to find the source
> id anywhere in this 5 events: When should i do it, at the time when i
> create stripe.checkout.session or in the webhook under this event
> checkout.session.completed? When i created customer on platofrm, it
> asks for a source,

Some clarifications:

- [Sources](https://stripe.com/docs/sources) is an older API mostly not relevant to Checkout. It uses the newer [Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods) API.
- I'd suggest looking at Payment Methods and focusing on using that
- If you want to clone *Payment Methods* to connected account, review [this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods).
- For later payments, you should create [Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents) supplying both the `customer` and `payment_method` using the customers [saved payment methods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-create-payment-intent-off-session) (checkout will create these).

Comment: "Checkout always collects a new Payment Method, so the idea of cloning from the platform is moot.", so how would i achive it using prebuilt checkout approach ? Do i need to switch to custom payment flow ? or i can still go with stripe prebuilt page, and achive the same thing using it ?

Comment: if yes, could you please tell me a high level approach programatically, at what stage i need to do what, just point me to right direction ? i have created a customer at platform, now i do get the payment method of platform in the event, at what event should i clone payment methds to connected account ?

Comment: i have followed this doc(https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods), a payment method is also created but I can not see it's reference any where on connected stripe account, under which section (payments ?), will i see the reference to this payment method of connected account ?

Comment: If you've created the payment method for the connected account, you won't "see it" in the dashboard unless you attached it to a Customer. The flow for this is usually: 1/ Manage customers and saved payments method on platform account, 2/ Clone PM to connected account for purchase, 3/ create customer on connected account & attach PM, 4/ Make payments using new connected account cust & PM. (Note: 3/ is optional, you can just go direct to the payment but you'll have to reclone for every payment then.)